# How can I map BINARY(16) to GUID with Dapper?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dapper, guid

I have data stored in the DB as `BINARY(16)` and I would like to select the data using dapper and have it mapped to a model property that is a `Guid`. What is a good way of doing this?

Dapper 1.50.4

Comment: Related: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/447

Comment: After reading that, I'm beginning to think storing as characters is a better solution, despite the fact that it's a waste of space

Comment: @JoePhillips Agreed. Also, vs BINARY(16) the values would be displayed rather than "BLOB" in MySql Workbench if using CHAR(36).

Answer (score 0):

If all your guid in our database are stored as BINARY(16) I would go on and create a Custom Type Handler to automatically convert the binary format to GUID. Something like:

```
class BinaryGuid {
  public Guid Guid;
  public BinaryGuid(byte[] binaryGuid) {
    <your-code-here>  
  } 
}

public class BinaryGuidHandler: SqlMapper.TypeHandler<BinaryGuid>
{
    public override Roles Parse(object value)
    {
        <your-code-here>
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, BinaryGuid value)
    {
        <your-code-here>
    }
}
```

then you register it for Dapper to use

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new BinaryGuidHandler());
```

and you should be good to go:

```
var r = conn.Query<BinaryGuid>("SELECT MyBinaryGuid FROM MyTable")
```

I've written an article (and samples) on how to manage custom types in Dapper here:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/custom-type-handling-4b447b97c620

Comment: This is probably the best shot at doing this but it would be good to see a warning that Guids can be stored in sevearl different formats (typically one which the DB would specify) but since mariadb doesn't specify one here, it's up to the user to determine which one to use. This could cause potential data corruption if not careful